# Let $f: \ \mathbb{R} \implies \mathbb{R} \ $ be defined by $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ is $f$ onto and one-to-one?

Tags: functions

Let $f: \ \mathbb{R} \implies \mathbb{R} \ $ be defined by $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ is $f$

1. onto
2. one-to-one

Question 1, what is a better way to write this up?

- $f$ is onto as there exists a value $x$ for every possible $f(x)$

Question 2, I know it is one-to-one but what is a nice way to write it up?

- $f$ is one-to-one as there exists a unique $x$ for every possible $f(x)$

I understand that neither of my answers would suffice as proofs but what is a good way to write up the answers so that they would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $y \in \mathbb R$, then $f(2y)=y.$  Conclusion ?
2. If $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $f(a)=f(b)$, then $\frac{a}{2}=\frac{b}{2}$, hence $a=b.$ Conclusion ?